# Displaying multiple rows in labels using dt.Rows

Tags: c#, ms-access-2016

I'm having trouble displaying non-existent rows with if-else in a table with labels.

I'm currently logged in with this `parentsID` (logged in as `New` session) with two children (two rows) and there are no problems with `dt.Rows[0]` and `dt.Rows[1]` except I'm getting error at `dt.Rows[2]` with this `Error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 2.` As for the `parentsID` with three children, there's no error. Likewise, if I log in with a `parentsID` that has only one `child` then it displays `There is no row at position 1.`

How do I fix this? My english is not good, sorry if there are grammatical errors.

I have one table called `family` and it has everyone in it. All rows have `childID`(their username) along with `parentsID`. some `child` can be a `parent` of other `childs`.

```
        try
        {

            string query = "select * from family where parentsID = '" + Session["New"] + "'";
            using (OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataReader myReader3 = null;
                myReader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

                if (myReader3.HasRows)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(myReader3);

                    if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows[0]["childID"]))
                    {
                        label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["childID"].ToString();
                        label2.Text = "$" + Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["childNetWorth"]).ToString("N2");
                        label3.Text = dt.Rows[0]["childName"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label1.Text = "-ID-";
                        label2.Text = "-";
                        label3.Text = "-";
                    }

                    if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows[1]["childID"]))
                    {
                        label5.Text = dt.Rows[1]["childID"].ToString();
                        label6.Text = "$" + Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[1]["childNetWorth"]).ToString("N2");
                        label7.Text = dt.Rows[1]["childName"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label5.Text = "-ID-";
                        label6.Text = "-";
                        label7.Text = "-";
                    }

                    if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows[2]["childID"]))
                    {
                        label9.Text = dt.Rows[2]["childID"].ToString();
                        label10.Text = "$" + Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[2]["childNetWorth"]).ToString("N2");
                        label11.Text = dt.Rows[2]["childName"].ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label9.Text = "-ID-";
                        label10.Text = "-";
                        label11.Text = "-";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a for loop to iterate `DataTable` contents may prevent such `IndexOutOfRangeException` hassle like this example:

```
if (myReader3.HasRows)
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Load(myReader3);

     for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         // label assignments here
     }
}
```

Depending on `dt.Rows.Count` value, iteration automatically stops if `i` reaching the maximum count value, hence `dt.Rows[i]` call doesn't throwing exception.

However, as Jon Skeet mentioned in [loop through an array of given labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791692/c-sharp-loop-through-an-array-of-given-labels) post, it's harder to find out which label will assigned to certain value for given setup even with help of array indexes (e.g. `{ 1, 5, 7 }` for `childID` labels). So far, this is the effort I can do to iterate `DataTable` contents then assign values into different labels as required:

```
if (myReader3.HasRows)
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Load(myReader3);

     for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows[i]["childID"]))
         {
             if (i == 0)
             {
                 label1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["childID"].ToString();
                 label2.Text = "$" + Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["childNetWorth"]).ToString("N2");
                 label3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["childName"].ToString();
             }
             else if (i == 1)
             {
                 label5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["childID"].ToString();
                 label6.Text = "$" + Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["childNetWorth"]).ToString("N2");
                 label7.Text = dt.Rows[i]["childName"].ToString();
             }
             else if (i == 2)
             {
                 label9.Text = dt.Rows[i]["childID"].ToString();
                 label10.Text = "$" + Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["childNetWorth"]).ToString("N2");
                 label11.Text = dt.Rows[i]["childName"].ToString();
             }
         }
         else
         {
             if (i == 0)
             {
                 label1.Text = "-ID-";
                 label2.Text = "-";
                 label3.Text = "-";
             }
             else if (i == 1)
             {
                 label5.Text = "-ID-";
                 label6.Text = "-";
                 label7.Text = "-";
             }
             else if (i == 2)
             {
                 label9.Text = "-ID-";
                 label10.Text = "-";
                 label11.Text = "-";
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: oh my god. thank you so much! marked as answer. thank you very much sir for your help!